# How to load a code source modified package in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ipython

I have downloaded from github a package (scikit-lean) and put the code source in repository folder (Windows 7 64-bit).

After modifying the code source, how can I load the package into the IPython notebook for testing ?

1. Should I copy paste the modified in sites-packages folder ?
   (what about the current original scikit-lean package)
2. Can I add the modified folder to the Python path ?
3. How to manage versioning when loading package in Python since both are same names ?
     (ie: the original package vs the package I modified)

Sorry, it looks like beginner questions, but could not find anything how to start with

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in a file called file.py, you should just be able to do `import file` (if you're not in the right folder, just run `cd folder`  in IPython first.)

Comment: This is a full pakcage with __init__ file.

How to manage versionning ?

Comment: what do you mean manage versioning ? like version control with git?